# Mocking ItemResponse in CosmosDB

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, moq, xunit

I am writing unit tests using Moq in xUnit for a service that involves CosmosDB. There's a method `GetVehicleInfo` which returns `ItemResponse<VehicleInfo>` from CosmosDB. As `ItemResponse` has a protected constructor so I can't new it up. Therefore, I'm mocking the caller method and doing

```
var responseMock = new Mock<ItemResponse<VehicleInfo>>();
responseMock.Setup(x => x.Resource).Returns(expectedItem); //expectedItem is of VehicleInfo type
cosmoRepoServiceStub.Setup(service => service.GetVehicleInfo("a1", "a2").Result).Returns(responseMock.Object);
```

The problem I face is that when `GetVehicleInfo` is called as below, it returns `null` always. I expect it to return `ItemResponse<VehicleInfo>` wherein `Resource` will contain `expectedItem`.

```
ItemResponse<VehicleInfo> response = await _cosmosRepo.GetVehicleInfo(plate, country);
if (response == null){ //... }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should setup your cosmoRepoServiceStub like this:

```
cosmoRepoServiceStub
    .Setup(service => service.GetVehicleInfo(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(responseMock.Object);
```

- `GetVehicleInfo` parameters should any string in the setup method
- Instead of calling the `.Result` inside the method selector please prefer `ReturnsAsync`

---

Or if you really need to anticipate `"a1"` as a first argument then define it as

```
const StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
cosmoRepoServiceStub
    .Setup(service => service.GetVehicleInfo(
       It.Is<string>(param1 => string.Equals(param1, "a1", comparison), 
       It.Is<string>(param1 => string.Equals(param1, "a2", comparison)))
    .ReturnsAsync(responseMock.Object);
```

---

**UPDATE #1** Reflect to comment

> Why does `It.IsAny` work whereas `"a1"` does not?

[Moq uses](https://github.com/moq/moq4/blob/main/src/Moq/Matchers/ConstantMatcher.cs) uses `object.Equals` under the hood to check the `Setup`'s argument against the actual invocation's argument.

This means that the comparison for value types and for strings are based on their values (not based on their references).

So, in your particular case that means either `plate` or `country` does not contain `a1` or `a2` strings respectively.

In short I should work, but as a general rule of thumb

- Make your `Setup` as generic as possible
- Make your `Verify` as specific as possible

Comment: In more recent [updates](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#async-methods) to the documentation the second bullet  point you made has been superseded. It does not make your answer incorrect in any way. was just bringing the updated documentation to your attention.

Comment: @Nkosi Ohh thanks, I did not know about it. Good to know thanks!

Comment: @PeterCsala Thank you for the answer. Initially, I was using ReturnsAsync but it didn't work with the hardcoded arguments to the GetVehicleInfo method. Just by changing it to It.IsAny<string>(), the test now starts to work. I fail to understand this. Can you please explain a bit? I had a look at the documentation but it's not explained there. I am confused because another test with hardcoded argument works fine. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Sarmad I've updated my post to reflect to your question, please check it. If you have found it useful then please consider to upvote and/or accept it as the answer.